# Django Python Check if the project is followed

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I'm currently working on a website that allows you to follow and unfollow projects. On the project page, there is a follow button, and if you click that button, you are now following the team, and the button should turn into unfollow afterwards.

Is a template tag that looks like {% if user.is_authenticated %} a good way to determine if the project is followed? Would I need to create a template tag and put it around my divs?

```
         <div class="progress-stats">
            <a href="{% url 'teams:follow' team.id %}">Follow
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="progress-stats">
            <a href="{% url 'teams:unfollow' team.id %}">Unfollow
            </a>
         </div>
```

Here is my model

```
class FollowTeam(models.Model):
team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
followed_by=models.ManyToManyField(FollowList, related_name='followed_by')

def __str__(self):
    return self.team.title

class FollowList(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='follow')
following = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name='following_team')
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.email
```

Comment: Why not just use javascript ?

Comment: @farhawa why should he use JavaScript? What in the question leads you to think that it would be an appropriate solution here? How would it even work?

Comment: @DanielRoseman would I need a custom template tag for this?

Comment: Assuming there's a many-to-many-relationship, you could just do sth like: `{% if request.user in team.followers.all %}` with the appropriate field name.

Comment: No, why? You just need some way of identifying if a project is followed; unfortunately you haven't provided any details of that or why if your models so it's not possible to tell you how.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm not using a many-to-many relationship in this case, would a many-to-many relationship be a better choice?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry I just started learning django, would what be the way to identify it? Would I need a class based view? or just a function under the model? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @RobertLi You DO have a many-to-many relationship. `FollowTeam` is your explicit through model. But `FollowList` sounds as if you want multiple users to belong to it, which meant you had the FK the wrong way round.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I see, Sorry I'm new to django programming. so would the template tag be {% if request.user in team.followteam.followed_by %}?

Comment: @RobertLi Nah, your model design is more complicated. Unless there are more fields in the models you have shown, it would make more sense to have a simple `ManyToManyField` from `Team` to `User`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl let's say I have a ManyToManyField from Team to User in my Team model, the Team model would have a list of users that follows that particular team right?

Comment: @RobertLi ... and vice versa, a user would have a list of teams.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I added 2 manytomany fields in each model, the many to many field in FollowTeam is from Followlist which is a foreignkey from Users. Would this be better than the previous design?